# How to add addition settings in node edit page on rightside bar

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

I want to add additional settings in node edit page (node/*/edit) on right side bar. How can i achieve this drupal 8?

[image: admin right side bar on node edit page]

**Update**

To be more clear, I have installed [url_redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect) module and it is showing settings in node edit page in drupal 7. But in drupal 8 there is no such settings. So I want add those settings by myself, but on right side bar.

[image: drupal 7 node edit page and settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to implement `hook_form_node_form_alter` function to add settings to node edit page. I did this by applying patch specified in https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2702353.

I specified a wrong module in my question (There were confusion, because both the modules showing same text), actual module that was showing settings in admin pane was [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module not [url_redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect).

I keep this answer here that may help someone who come across the same question I had.